# geometric description of a set of vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can you please check my work?

Question : give the geometric description of span{(1,1,2),(0,1,4),(-1,0,2)}

Attempt : $v_1 = v_2 - v_3$. Therefore the set is linearly dependent, and $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly independent. Therefore the set span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Can you help me get the equation of the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: I think you mean the set spans a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. As for how to find the equation of said plane, use the two independent vectors in the plane, and take their cross product to find a normal vector.

Comment: what will be the point?

Comment: A point in this plane will be $(0,0,0)$. In fact, any subspace of this vector space must contain this point, because it contains the 0 vector.